# Difference maintaining state on server-side and maintaining state on client-side

Tags: state, server-side, client-side

First I want to clarify what is the *maintaining state* and *stateless* concepts.

And as the title says, what is the difference between an application maintaining the **state on server-side** and other maintaining the **state on client-side**. What its advantages and disadvantages? I want to understand more clearly these concepts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major difference is where the data is stored.

Storing the state on client-side means that it will be stored on the device itself. This makes it more challenging to share that data and manipulate it without doing so on the device. The major advantage here is privacy and security. The server won't be able to view the state which increases the privacy of that data.

Storing on the server-side means it will be stored on some other server. This makes it easier to share that data and manipulate it without approval from the device itself. Major downside is anyone who has access to that server can view **all** users data. Which can be a major privacy concern.

That is a high level overview of it. There are a lot of pros and cons to each and it truly depends on what data you will be storing and how you want to use it.

Comment: What should I consider to decide which approach to use?

Comment: @ThiagoMedeiros The things I mentioned above. Without more detail it's hard to give a specific answer. But things like, will you need to manipulate data without doing so on the users device? Do you need to access that data for some reason? Is user privacy a major concern (should always be on some level)? How will you protect that user data? Will that user data need to be shared between users?